# How can I display hash data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% @user.dids.each_with_index{ |did, i| %>
  <li><%=h @user.dids %></li>
<% } %>
```

result  to display

```
#<Did:0x7fc4c55f4bf0>#<Did:0x7fc4c55f4ba0>#
<Did:0x7fc4c55f4b50>#<Did:0x7fc4c55f4b00>#
<Did:0x7fc4c55f4a88>#<Did:0x7fc4c55f4a10>#
<Did:0x7fc4c55f49c0>#<Did:0x7fc4c55f4970>
```

I almost sleep and did not think, tell me somebody how to display the hash data

Comment: How you want to show this? Fastest way I can think is by using `@user.dids.inspect`. But this is not like, user friendly. P)

Comment: We don't know what the data looks like: is each array element a hash? Display the key and value?

Comment: value, data for output is a numbers ex. 00123123123

Comment: please show me less than 2 variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I sleep so correctly

```
<% @user.dids.each_with_index{ |did, i| %>
  <li><%= did.did %></li>
<% } %>
```

Thank you for helping colleagues

Comment: You could also use a .map method:
`<%= @user.dids.map { |did| "<li>#{did.did}</li>".html_safe } %>`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the debug function in rails

```
<%= debug @user %>
```

Comment: It displays the hash data, just sayin.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your loop is a bit strange. It seems to me that you should have

```
<% @user.dids.each_with_index{ |did, i| %>
  <li><%=h did %></li>
<% } %>
```

In your version, you are printing the entire `@user.dids` with each iteration.

Also, how is the class `Did` defined? If you are in Rails and `Did` is an ActiveRecord model, you should have the `.to_json` method available to you (options and info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)):

```
<% @user.dids.each_with_index{ |did, i| %>
  <li><%=h did.to_json %></li>
<% } %>
```